# UWP Is there a way to disable Acrylic for the entire app and use the fallback color always?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, acrylic-material

Im currently working on a UWP app that looks something like this with Acrylic on the left panel:
[image: A picture of my app]

Now when I enable power saving mode on my laptop, the acrylic gets replaced with its fallback color:

[image: Power saving pic]

Now I want an option in my app's settings screen to disable acrylic throughout the app, and have the fallback color be used always. Im not sure where to begin however. [This seems promising](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush.alwaysusefallback?view=winrt-18362) but I'm not sure how I'd implement it without having to go through every single acrylic material in the app and add code to disable it.

Is there a top level setting that I could use to do this? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush.alwaysusefallback?view=winrt-18362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CustomResource` to decide how to display your AcrylicBrush:

**Prepare**

In the question description, you need a top-level setting to switch the Acrylic effect. Here you can use `LocalSettings`.

*Tool.cs*

```cs
public class Tool
{
    public static void WriteLocalSetting(string key, object value)
    {
        var localSetting = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSetting.Values[key.ToString()] = value;
    }
    public static object GetLocalSetting(string key, object defaultValue)
    {
        var localSetting = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        bool isKeyExist = localSetting.Values.ContainsKey(key.ToString());
        if (isKeyExist)
        {
            return localSetting.Values[key.ToString()];
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLocalSetting(key, defaultValue);
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Ddefine**

According to the documentation of [CustomResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/customresource-markup-extension), you need to create a derived class.

```cs
public class CustomResourceLoader : CustomXamlResourceLoader
{
    protected override object GetResource(string resourceId, string objectType, string propertyName, string propertyType)
    {
        if (resourceId == "MyBackground")
        {
            bool isUseAcrylic = (bool)Tool.GetLocalSetting("IsUseAcrylic", true);
            var brush = new AcrylicBrush();
            brush.TintColor = Colors.White;
            brush.BackgroundSource = AcrylicBackgroundSource.HostBackdrop;
            brush.TintOpacity = 0.7;
            brush.FallbackColor = Colors.White;
            brush.AlwaysUseFallback = !isUseAcrylic;
            return brush;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

*App.xaml.cs*

```cs
public App()
{
    // ...
    CustomXamlResourceLoader.Current = new CustomResourceLoader();
}
```

*MainPage*

```xml
<Grid Background="{CustomResource MyBackground}">
    <ToggleSwitch Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Tool.WriteLocalSetting("IsUseAcrylic", (sender as ToggleSwitch).IsOn);
    // Need Re-render
}
```

It should be noted that switching at runtime will not affect the already rendered elements. After the modification, you can pop up a `MessageDialog` asking the user to restart the application to re-render.

Thanks.

Comment: Works as intended, thank you.

One way to not require restarting was to go through each element using the acrylic brush and re-set the brush, though that kind of defeats the purpose of "without having to go through every single acrylic material in the app and add code to disable it."

Answer (score 0):

You can place this code to App.xaml or your ShellPage's resources.

You can set the color as you want. This will override the default color.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" Color="Red" />
```